# window.print() doesn't work in Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

### HTML code

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:printPage();" style="display:inline-block;">Printer Friendly</a>
```

### JS code

```
function printPage() { 
    var printWin= window.open("", "displayWindow",
            "toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,"+"
             copyhistory=0,width=1000,height=700"); 

    printWin.document.write('<div id="header"><h3 id="page-title">Print Page Title</h3> ' +
             '<button onclick="window.print();" class="print-btn">Print</button></div>');

...


    printWin.document.close();  

}
```

On click of "Printer Friendly" link it ll fire popup window. There is one "Print" button available. usually on click of it ll fire `window.print()` window to print but it not fire any action in Samsung Galaxy Tab. Any idea or suggestion about if any code change is required here?

Comment: are you trying to access the page in android browser or webview as you have included android tag ? context is still not clear

Comment: Hi Pablo,
I have one html page. there one link "Printer Friendly" on click of it will give one popup window. In that popup window I have one print button on click it not fire any action. I havent added android tag. It happening in sumsung galaxy tab.

Comment: is it a website, the page of which u r opening in android browser of Samsung tab?

Comment: Yes. Web application. it made up of java, web technology, knockout js etc.

Comment: what happens in window based browsers or other u tried. Mean to say what are you trying to do in window.print() ?